# PDF file have two trailers?

Tags: file-format, struct, pdf

If I analyse multiple PDF files with a hex editor, I see that all of them have two trailers.
That's possible if an object has changed or renewed (https://blog.idrsolutions.com/multiple-trailers-in-a-pdf-file/), but in my case, the PDF files are not edited.
Does anyone know why all of the analysed files have two trailers?

This is a PDF file that contains a lot of text and also two images:

```
0001a30bh: 74 72 61 69 6C 65 72 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 53 69 7A 65 ; trailer..<</Size
0001a31bh: 20 34 37 2F 52 6F 6F 74 20 31 20 30 20 52 2F 49 ;  47/Root 1 0 R/I
0001a32bh: 6E 66 6F 20 31 35 20 30 20 52 2F 49 44 5B 3C 45 ; nfo 15 0 R/ID[<E
0001a33bh: 42 33 46 46 33 41 31 45 33 37 33 43 36 34 45 39 ; B3FF3A1E373C64E9
0001a34bh: 31 30 45 33 46 42 43 34 45 37 38 39 31 33 43 3E ; 10E3FBC4E78913C>
0001a35bh: 3C 45 42 33 46 46 33 41 31 45 33 37 33 43 36 34 ; <EB3FF3A1E373C64
0001a36bh: 45 39 31 30 45 33 46 42 43 34 45 37 38 39 31 33 ; E910E3FBC4E78913
0001a37bh: 43 3E 5D 20 3E 3E 0D 0A 73 74 61 72 74 78 72 65 ; C>] >>..startxre
0001a38bh: 66 0D 0A 31 30 36 33 32 33 0D 0A 25 25 45 4F 46 ; f..106323..%%EOF
0001a39bh: 0D 0A 78 72 65 66 0D 0A 30 20 30 0D 0A 74 72 61 ; ..xref..0 0..tra
0001a3abh: 69 6C 65 72 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 53 69 7A 65 20 34 37 ; iler..<</Size 47
0001a3bbh: 2F 52 6F 6F 74 20 31 20 30 20 52 2F 49 6E 66 6F ; /Root 1 0 R/Info
0001a3cbh: 20 31 35 20 30 20 52 2F 49 44 5B 3C 45 42 33 46 ;  15 0 R/ID[<EB3F
0001a3dbh: 46 33 41 31 45 33 37 33 43 36 34 45 39 31 30 45 ; F3A1E373C64E910E
0001a3ebh: 33 46 42 43 34 45 37 38 39 31 33 43 3E 3C 45 42 ; 3FBC4E78913C><EB
0001a3fbh: 33 46 46 33 41 31 45 33 37 33 43 36 34 45 39 31 ; 3FF3A1E373C64E91
0001a40bh: 30 45 33 46 42 43 34 45 37 38 39 31 33 43 3E 5D ; 0E3FBC4E78913C>]
0001a41bh: 20 2F 50 72 65 76 20 31 30 36 33 32 33 2F 58 52 ;  /Prev 106323/XR
0001a42bh: 65 66 53 74 6D 20 31 30 35 39 37 32 3E 3E 0D 0A ; efStm 105972>>..
0001a43bh: 73 74 61 72 74 78 72 65 66 0D 0A 31 30 37 34 32 ; startxref..10742
0001a44bh: 31 0D 0A 25 25 45 4F 46                         ; 1..%%EOF
```

This is a PDF file that does only contain some random characters:

```
000071cbh: 74 72 61 69 6C 65 72 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 53 69 7A 65 ; trailer..<</Size
000071dbh: 20 32 33 2F 52 6F 6F 74 20 31 20 30 20 52 2F 49 ;  23/Root 1 0 R/I
000071ebh: 6E 66 6F 20 39 20 30 20 52 2F 49 44 5B 3C 39 46 ; nfo 9 0 R/ID[<9F
000071fbh: 46 31 32 45 31 43 30 41 35 36 44 42 34 38 41 33 ; F12E1C0A56DB48A3
0000720bh: 41 31 43 37 32 30 33 38 32 33 30 32 45 32 3E 3C ; A1C720382302E2><
0000721bh: 39 46 46 31 32 45 31 43 30 41 35 36 44 42 34 38 ; 9FF12E1C0A56DB48
0000722bh: 41 33 41 31 43 37 32 30 33 38 32 33 30 32 45 32 ; A3A1C720382302E2
0000723bh: 3E 5D 20 3E 3E 0D 0A 73 74 61 72 74 78 72 65 66 ; >] >>..startxref
0000724bh: 0D 0A 32 38 36 35 39 0D 0A 25 25 45 4F 46 0D 0A ; ..28659..%%EOF..
0000725bh: 78 72 65 66 0D 0A 30 20 30 0D 0A 74 72 61 69 6C ; xref..0 0..trail
0000726bh: 65 72 0D 0A 3C 3C 2F 53 69 7A 65 20 32 33 2F 52 ; er..<</Size 23/R
0000727bh: 6F 6F 74 20 31 20 30 20 52 2F 49 6E 66 6F 20 39 ; oot 1 0 R/Info 9
0000728bh: 20 30 20 52 2F 49 44 5B 3C 39 46 46 31 32 45 31 ;  0 R/ID[<9FF12E1
0000729bh: 43 30 41 35 36 44 42 34 38 41 33 41 31 43 37 32 ; C0A56DB48A3A1C72
000072abh: 30 33 38 32 33 30 32 45 32 3E 3C 39 46 46 31 32 ; 0382302E2><9FF12
000072bbh: 45 31 43 30 41 35 36 44 42 34 38 41 33 41 31 43 ; E1C0A56DB48A3A1C
000072cbh: 37 32 30 33 38 32 33 30 32 45 32 3E 5D 20 2F 50 ; 720382302E2>] /P
000072dbh: 72 65 76 20 32 38 36 35 39 2F 58 52 65 66 53 74 ; rev 28659/XRefSt
000072ebh: 6D 20 32 38 33 37 34 3E 3E 0D 0A 73 74 61 72 74 ; m 28374>>..start
000072fbh: 78 72 65 66 0D 0A 32 39 32 37 35 0D 0A 25 25 45 ; xref..29275..%%E
0000730bh: 4F 46                                           ; OF
```

Comment: It may depend on which tool you're using to create the files, I don't see that behavior.. which PDF writer are you using?